# Socket server with epoll gives unknown bytes at disconnect

Tags: c++, c, sockets, serialization, epoll

I have a socket server in C++ and I am using epoll. I am sending to the server a char that contains a HeaderPacket and the NormalPacket.
First I am reading the HeaderPacket and after that I am reading the NormalPacket.

And now the problem, when I close the client ( I was trying to use close and shutdown - same output ) I get some weird bytes on the first recv ( the one that reads the header packet ) and after that segmentation fault.

Also, when I change the size of my content char from HeaderPacket to another value for example 120 I don't get segmentation fault but when I set it to 40 or other value I get the segmentation fault.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 256
#define CHARSIZE 40
```

**Here is the function that I use it for reading:**

```
void PacketHandler::ReadBytes(int fd, struct HeaderPacket &hp, char buffer[])

{

    int reading = 0;

    ssize_t hpCount, cpCount;

    char hpBuffer[6];



    hpCount = recv(fd, hpBuffer, 6, 0);

    if(hpCount <= 0)

    {

       reading = 1;

    } else {  

        this->UnserializeHeaderPacket(hpBuffer, hp);

        print(DEBUG, Helpers::IntegerToString(hp.length)); 

        cpCount = hp.length;

        char cpBuffer[cpCount];

        memset(cpBuffer, 0, sizeof(cpBuffer));

        char* iterator = cpBuffer;

        int bytesLeft = sizeof(cpBuffer) - sizeof(char);

        print(DEBUG, Helpers::IntegerToString(bytesLeft)); 

        if(bytesLeft < 0)

        {

            reading = 1;

        }

        while(bytesLeft > 0)

        {

            ssize_t curr;

            curr = recv(fd, iterator, bytesLeft, 0);



            if(curr == -1)

            {

                if(errno != EAGAIN)

                {

                    reading = 1;

                    print(WARNING, "reading error at content packet");

                }

                break;

            } else if(curr == 0) {

                reading = 1;

                break;

            } 



            iterator += curr;

            bytesLeft -= curr;                 





        }



            memcpy(buffer, cpBuffer, sizeof cpBuffer);     

    }



    if(reading)

    {

        print(NOTICE, "Closed connection with the descriptor " + Helpers::IntegerToString(fd));

        close(fd);

    }

}
```

**Here is the function for epoll**

```
void EventHandler::RunningLoop(int fd)

{

    while(1)

    {

        int availableEvents, i;



        availableEvents = epoll_wait(this->efd, this->events, MAXEVENTS, -1);

        for(i = 0; i < availableEvents; i++)

        {

            if(this->events[i].data.fd == fd)

            {

                // Accepting new connection

                this->AcceptClient(fd);

                continue;

            }

            else if((this->events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (this->events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(this->events[i].events & EPOLLIN)))

            {

                print(WARNING, "epoll error on reading from fd");

                close (this->events[i].data.fd);

                continue;

            } 

            else if(this->events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) 

            {

                print(WARNING, "intern close socket");

                close (this->events[i].data.fd);



            } else {

                // Reading packets

                this->run->InitializePacket(this->events[i].data.fd); // cals the read function

            }

        }

    }



    free(this->events);

    close(fd);

}
```

**My packets:**

```
struct HeaderPacket

{

    uint16_t opcode;

    uint32_t length;

};



struct HelloWorldPacket

{

    uint16_t byteOrder;

    char content[CHARSIZE];

};
```

**Function for serialization:**

```
void PacketHandler::SerializeHeaderPacket(HeaderPacket packet, char buffer[])

{

    uint16_t u16;

    uint32_t u32;



    u16 = htons(packet.opcode);

    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);

    u32 = htonl(packet.length);

    memcpy(buffer+2, &u32, 4);

}



void PacketHandler::UnserializeHeaderPacket(char buffer[], HeaderPacket &packet)

{

    uint16_t u16;

    uint32_t u32;



    memcpy(&u16, buffer+0, 2);

    packet.opcode = ntohs(u16);

    memcpy(&u32, buffer+2, 4);

    packet.length = ntohl(u32);

}



void PacketHandler::SerializeHelloWorldPacket(HelloWorldPacket packet, char buffer[])

{

    uint16_t u16;



    u16 = htons(packet.byteOrder);

    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);

    memcpy(buffer+2, &packet.content, sizeof packet.content);

}



void PacketHandler::UnserializeHelloWorldPacket(char buffer[], HelloWorldPacket &packet)

{

    uint16_t u16;



    memcpy(&u16, buffer+0, 2);

    packet.byteOrder = ntohs(u16);



    strcpy(packet.content, buffer+2);



}
```

And this is how I send data to server:

```
int EventHandler::SendHelloWorld(int fd)

{

    HeaderPacket hp;

    HelloWorldPacket hc;

    char buffer[256];

    int sendResult;

    char message[] = "hello_first_message\r\n";





    hp.opcode = HELLOWORLD;

    hp.length = sizeof message;

    memcpy(hc.content, message, sizeof message);





    packets->SerializeHeaderPacket(hp, buffer);

    packets->SerializeHelloWorldPacket(hc, buffer+6);



    sendResult = write(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);







    return sendResult;



}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does it compile without error and warnings?

Comment: When the connection is closed (`recv` returns 0), do you remove the socket from the epoll set?

Comment: @Joachim PileBorg I use close(fd) is not enough ? Thanks.

Comment: @stefanB Yes, it compiles without warnings and errors.

Comment: Disregard my comment. If you don't duplicate the socket descriptor (with e.g. `dup` etc.) then it should be removed from the set automatically when closed.

Comment: Where do you call `PacketHandler::ReadBytes`? And a suggestion, after a call to `recv` log the returned value to make sure you get all the data you want in the call.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this function this->run->InitializePacket(this->events[i].data.fd); // cals the read function
contains the call to ReadBytes and nothing else. In function PacketHandler::ReadBytes I check the returning value from recv for -1 or 0 .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6999/discussion-between-cemycc-and-joachim-pileborg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. 
When I write to the server I was using *sizeof buffer* and buffer is 256 length and I don't read 256 bytes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean a client can crash your server?  I hope you intend to fix this on the server side as well.  Your "unserializeHelloWorld" function is inheriently insecure. Do I need to elaborate on why?

  Also, "valgrind" is a very useful tool for diagnosing mysterious crashes like this. It likely would have flagged your buffer overrun at the specific place in code before the crash.

Comment: @selbie can you please explain why is insecure ? Thanks, I will try valgrind.

Comment: Bug #1: "ReadBytes" function. It reads 6 bytes and feeds that into UnserializeHeaderPacket.  A bad buy (with his own client code) connects to your server and sends these6 bytes as the headerpacket bytestream: {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}. UnserializeHeaderPacket will initialize "hp.length" member to be 4294967295 (that's 4GB).Then you will allocate that amount of memory via the call to "char cpBuffer[cpCount];"  I'm pretty certain that will crash your server. And if it doesn't, the "memcpy(buffer, cpBuffer, sizeof cpBuffer)" statement at the bottom of the function most certainly will.

Comment: Bug #1.1: Knowing that your buffer size is "256", I can send the following byte stream {0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff}.  That's only 64K of an allocation for the cpBuffer declaration. Now my client stream sends up 64K of data - most of which are x86 opcodes. When you do that memcpy statement at the bottom of ReadBytes, I could trigger a "buffer overrun" and now have your server execute my program code.  Newer compilers might insert safeguards to prevent this, but it will crash regardless.  This is called a buffer overrun.  Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Comment: Bug #2: UnserializeHelloWorldPacket calls strcpy to copy the network buffer into the packet.content buffer (which is only 40 bytes). What if the sender sent exactly 40 bytes, but didn't null terminate his message? Even though you memset(cpBuffer) before hand, if I sent you exactly that many bytes without a null char, your strcpy would copy into invalid memory.  And if I sent more than 40 bytes, I've exploited another buffer overrun in your code.

Comment: Conclusion: When you are writing socket and networking code, you should code as if the peer sending you data is trying to exploit you. Message sizes and packet structures need to be validated before doing buffer copies. Parsing code needs to be written very defensively, and preferable fuzz tested.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @selbie didn't know about this problems, I will try to fix them but the problem is if I don't send the lenght of my packet I don't know how much to read. I will try to find a solution after reading about Buffer overflow. Anyway, thanks for the help. Now i know what I have done wrong.

Comment: It's perfectly normal to put the data length in the header. But your server should enforce size limits. That is, if it sees a packet header that's declaring a length larger than your buffer size just drop the message and close the connection.

Comment: Another bug. I'm not certain if your AcceptConnection puts the remote client socket into a non-blocking state. In a blocking socket case, the client could send a header, but no data after than and just leave your server hung on a recv() call. If the client socket has been made non-blocking, then there's another bug that will impact legitimate clients. A client TCP stream may get fragmented and packets may be momentarily delayed - and recv() will return -1 (errno==EGAIN) even though more data may be incoming. Your code will drop the legitimate connection....

Comment: ... a good idea would be to allocate  "context object" for each new connection that includes the packet buffer and your own internal state variables for the connection.  The context object can be attached to the epoll.data.ptr member and referenced on subsequent epoll notifications. When I write TCP code, I write it as if recv() was only going to return "1 byte at a time".

Comment: @selbie My AcceptConnection function use int SocketServer::ChangeSocketType(int tfd) in this function I set the client socket to a non-blocking state using fcntl. Can you give me a hint please how to fix the last bug ? Because I am writing this server for a Collaborative real-time editor and I can't delay any data.

Comment: @selbie I understood, When a client will connect I will set the buffer to the ptr object from epoll and all the income data will be inserted there and when the client will stop sending data the buffer will be destroyed right ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7050/discussion-between-selbie-and-cemycc)